# How to get the contents of a specific revision of a file using subclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, repository, subclipse

I'm trying to get two versions of a file using subclipse so that they can be compared, the comparison is not the issue and is essentially unimportant.

I'm having trouble finding how exactly I can get a File from the repository, and have been unable to find any real reference material for the API.

If someone could tell me which classes/methods I should use, or even could link me to a reference document that I could use I'd be very thankful!

Comment: Are you trying to do this in your IDE or programmatically? If you are asking about the IDE, try opening the History View. There you can compare versions, retrieve them from the repository or compare them to each other.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is:

> Right click > Compare With > Revision > ...

You get a list of revisions to compare to. Once selected, you see the whole revision in the right-hand panel and the diffs highlighted. If you want, you can just highlight the whole thing and copy-paste it somewhere.